# Extracting Data from Mirrored RAID Volume

Tags: mirroring, raid, scsi

I have a Dell PowerEdge 1750 thats dead now.

Inside was raid 1 (mirror) volume of two SCSI hard drives.

I need some data from those drives.

If I attach one of them to another SCSI controller will I be able to see data?

If not, what are my options?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I've had several instances where I've been able to remove drives from RAID 1 arrays and successfully read them individually using desktops and even USB housings (for the SATA) - both SCSI and SATA. However, some controllers put some "metadata" on the FS and that can make them incompatible with any other controllers.

I'm not familiar with the PowerEdge 1750, but a quick eBay search shows dual Xeon MBs available for them priced at below $25, delivered. There are a wide variety of low-priced other components available there, too. So, I guess that it's really a matter of what it's worth to you.

I can say that I've never harmed the contents of a RAID element by plugging it into another (non RAID) controller, so if I were in your position, I'd try that with a couple of SCSI-equipped computers and, if that fails, I'd consider buying the parts to fix the 1750. You can always sell the machine or part it out on eBay if cost is a serious consideration.

Hmmm, I think that I may still have a couple of SCSI machines laying around here somewhere...

Good luck with whatever you end up trying - and please, let us know how you solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd kill for one of those scsi machines of yours, because i need to get that data like yesterday :) But hard disks are ULTRA 320 SCSI with 80-pins, hot pluggable. I even have one SCSI controller of my own, but its standard 68-pin. No luck there. Well...

Comment: I've used 68 to 80 adapters going both ways - 80 pin controller to 68 pin drive and vice, versa. You can get these on eBay for $2 or $3. The only difference between a 68 pin drive and an 80 pin one is that the 80 pin one has 12 pins for (hot-swappable) power connections, the data lines are identical. I used to have several 68 to 80 cables (both with and w/o power connectors), but the adapters are much cleaner as they break-out the power to standard connectors.

Comment: With that controller, and one of these adapters, you should be good to go: http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_trksid=p5197.m570.l1313&_nkw=scsi+68+to+80&_sacat=0